# nulls from source for number data type from source handling

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

how to handle null from source column which is a number example

source column revenue

```
nvl(TO_CHAR(revenue), ' ') revenue
```

basically i have only few records which have values from the source and i shouldn't loose the data how to handle ?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: What is your question? Clearly explain your requirement and desired output.